# Excel 2010 VBA. input box is deleting formula in cell that it changes

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Ok, I'm fairly new to VBA. In fact, I'm a data guy and don't use it much so please forgive me for my lack of knowledge.

I have a cell in a sheet that derives it's value from another cell. In other words, cell b1 = a1. I am using an input box to change the value of b1 because this is sometimes needed. I do not want to change cell a1, and want to maintain the formula in b1 so that cell b1 will normally derive value from a1.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton_click ()
Dim myValue As Variant
myValue = InputBox ("change cell b1")
Range ("b1"). Value = myValue
End Sub
```

This works to change the value but deletes the formula. I am using an activeX button to initiate the input box. Can this button override the formula for user purposes but still maintain the formula for future calculations? 95% of the time I need b1 to derive value from a1, but when I over ride it I need the formula to not be deleted so it can be used by the next user.

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a VBa issue or not... A cell can't be both a value and a formula. You could, depending on your needs, simply grab the formula. Something like `Range("A1").Formula`, save it as a global variable and re-apply/use it later.

Comment: Thank you. In the context of my code, how would I use this?

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to implement this is with a **third cell**.

Say we use **C1** as the override:

If **C1** is empty, then use the value in **A1**.
If **C1** is not empty, then use it.

So in **B1** enter:

```
=IF(C1="",A1,C1)
```

and have the macro update **C1**.